# MySQL - delete entry created within seconds/range

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sql-delete

I am using MySQL database with following structure:

```html
sensor         value           timestamp    
 1              10         2017-01-25 06:00:00    
 2              12         2017-01-25 06:20:00       
 2              12         2017-01-25 06:20:05
 3              30         2017-01-25 06:23:00
```

As you can see for sensor 2 there are multiple entries, which were created within a few seconds. I would like to delete one of those 2 entries, which have been created in a time range of 10 seconds. How can I select/delete them?

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a IN clause on the max timestamp tuple

```
 delete from my_table 
 where (sensor, timestamp) in (
     select sensor, max(timestamp)
     from my_table 
     group by sensor,   
     having count(*) >1

 )
```

and for time range for duplicated deletion of 10 seconds

```
delete from my_table 
where (sensor, timestamp) in (

  select sensor, max(timestamp)
  from my_table 
  group by sensor,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 10 
)
```

and for avoid the select/delete table  you could use a join on a subselect

```
 delete from my_table 
 inner join (

  select sensor, max(timestamp) my_max
  from my_table 
  group by sensor,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 10 

 ) t on t.sensor = my_table.sensor and  t.my_max = my_table.timestamp
```

Comment: thanks. You mean "group by sensor" ? So I only get one of the two entries?

Comment: Problem is, if I do this, it will also select the ones which have only one entry in the table.

Comment: asnwer updated .wih check for delete duplicated  rows  only

Comment: The time range problem is not solved. As I have several entries for sensor 2 within a time range of a few seconds. For each case they are created within a few seconds I'd like to delete one of them.

Comment: what's the time range for deletion  ??'

Comment: Hi again, I actually realized now, that the select statement wil work but not the delete statement. Error #1093 - From clause in target table not allowed. Any ideas to avoid this?